# how to install android emulator in windows10

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner at `react-native`.

Follow, there is an error when installing.

`com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!`

So, I think that I'm going to install the emulator
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

[The Android Studio Solution:](https://developer.android.com/studio/install)

- Open Android Studio
- Open project
- Navigate to Tools > Android > AVD manager
- You may create an emulator here, or launch an existing one.